# How do I replace Function create from MooTools 1.2 to 1.3?

Tags: mootools

Hi there i have this code snippet I need to get working with MooTools 1.3 :

```
this.fn = function (e, cal) {
    var e = new Event(e);
    var el = e.target;
    var stop = false;

    while (el != document.body && el.nodeType == 1) {
        if (el == this.calendar) { stop = true; }
        this.calendars.each(function (kal) {
            if (kal.button == el || kal.els.contains(el)) { stop = true; }
        });

        if (stop) {
            e.stop();
            return false;
        }
        else { el = el.parentNode; }
    }
    this.toggle(cal);
}.create({
             'arguments': cal, 
             'bind': this, 
             'event': true 
        }); <-- THIS CREATE METHOD DOES NOT WORK
```

Can someone help me whit this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i said on the mootools user mailing list, i don't know about the "perfect" way, but in the meantime you can always (if you don't want to use the 1.2 compat version) 
inspire yourself from the implementation of the function for 1.2 compat :

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/025adc07dc7e9851f30b3911961d43d525d83847/Source/Types/Function.js#L74

I have to admit the doc for 1.3 only mention that this method is deprecated.

Comment: That was what i saw too, I will look for another more resent script ;o)

Comment: have you tried `Function.from` with a bind? probably http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/7YNK7/ although all you really need is http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/7YNK7/1/ imo. bindWithEvent is gone...

Comment: also, do not use `new Event(e).stop()` but use `e.stop` and check for `e && e.stop` first (in case you do `.fireEvent()` manually. reliance on `e.target` should also be avoided if possible as it makes `fireEvent()` even more difficult (you need to pass on a dummy event object containing `target: someEl` as a property)

Comment: and really, don't waste your time. http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_datepicker

Answer (score 2):

After create function was deprecated, you need to "manually" recreate the usage.
In this case, you are creating a function that will be an event listener and binding it later in the code (this is Aeron Glemann's calendar).

So what you need to do, is put this function in addEvent you find directly below it, like this.

```
document.addEvent('mousedown', function(e, cal) {
[...]
}.bind(this));
```

Also, there's a removeEvent call at the begining of the function you're currently editing (the toggle function) that will no longer work since this function no longer has a name, replace it with removing all events on mousedown, worked for me.

```
document.removeEvents('mousedown');
```